# Magento 1.8 Some orders did not generate an invoice (flat tables were not disabled)

Tags: magento-1.8, sql

> Culprit: Human mistake: Flat Tables Were Enabled when order was set to 'process': Invoice is not generated.
>
> > I need to retrieve all processed orders with no invoice. An SQL query could do that. Has anyone experienced that issue and has suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this and got results, but it will return canceled orders, I guess I need to add other tables to get desired results:

> > select
> >
> > _order.increment_id as 'Order Number',
> >     _invoice.increment_id as 'Invoice Number'
> >
> > from sales_flat_order  _order
> >
> > left join sales_flat_invoice  _invoice
> >          on _order.entity_id = _invoice.order_id
> >
> > ```
> > where
> >
> > _invoice.order_id is null
> > ```